# Trying to get multiple maps to show up on their corresponding pages

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

The first map shows up but the second map does not. 
I'm getting  Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null which should indicate that the ids match but they do. Id is declared inside the div. Is the javascript code wrong? 
[image]

[image]

```
<div id="map">location 1</div>
<div id="map2">location 2</div>


var map;
var map2;

function initMap() {
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.503691, -80.061847),
    zoom: 15
});

map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map2'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.503691, -79.984257),
    zoom: 6
});
}
```

[image]

Comment: there is no div with id="maps" on your page (its id is "map2")

Comment: Ya know, I had went in there changed it from map2 to maps. I changed it back. I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: the id's match. check it again

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue (including any CSS that defined the map's size). BTW, if it is a different page, you should be able to use the same HTML.